# Google Play Billing API in a PWA app built with Blazor WASM

Tags: javascript, blazor, google-play, progressive-web-apps, blazor-webassembly

I am developing a PWA in Blazor Web Assembly (WASM). I have the basic app functionality working and have deployed an internal release via Google Play which works.

The next step is to get Google Play billing working. This is difficult because there doesn't seem to be any way to work with the code in a development environment. The APIs only work in an app deployed through the Google Play store. I have a page which calls javascript via JS interop, and with some some simple code I can show that both the Developer and Billing APIs are available by hiding/showing divs.

So I have tried to expand this to pull my test subscription product out and display it. This is my Google Play billing code now (the GOOGLE PLAY BILLING section is where the problem is, the parts outside of that all work as expected):

```
window.checkDigitalGoodsApi = async () => {
    setTimeout(async () => { // Wrap the callback in an async function
        const divGoogleDigitalGoodsAndBilling = document.getElementById('divGoogleDigitalGoodsAndBilling');
        const divGoogleDigitalGoodsOnly = document.getElementById('divGoogleDigitalGoodsOnly');
        const divNeither = document.getElementById('divNeither');

        if ('getDigitalGoodsService' in window) {
            // Digital Goods API is supported!
            try {
                const service = await window.getDigitalGoodsService('https://play.google.com/billing');
                // Google Play Billing is supported!
                divGoogleDigitalGoodsAndBilling.hidden = false;
                divGoogleDigitalGoodsOnly.hidden = true;
                divNeither.hidden = true;

                // -- GOOGLE PLAY BILLING ----------------------------

                // Get a reference to the div element
                const divProductDetails = document.getElementById('divProductDetails');

                // Get SKU product details
                const svcProductDetails = await service.getDetails(['goldmonthly1']);

                // Loop through (only will have one) and create text for item
                for (const itmProduct of svcProductDetails) {

                    divProductDetails.innerHTML = `<h3>${itmProduct.title}</h3>
                        <p>${itmProduct.description}</p>
                        <p>Price: ${itmProduct.price}</p>`;
                }

                // -- END --------------------------------------------

            } catch (error) {
                // Google Play Billing is not available. Use another payment flow.
                divGoogleDigitalGoodsAndBilling.hidden = true;
                divGoogleDigitalGoodsOnly.hidden = false;
                divNeither.hidden = true;
            }
        } else {
            // Digital Goods API is not supported
            divGoogleDigitalGoodsAndBilling.hidden = true;
            divGoogleDigitalGoodsOnly.hidden = true;
            divNeither.hidden = false;
        }
    }, 0); // Add a timeout of 0 milliseconds to ensure the page is fully rendered.
};
```

The nested "async" wrappers seems a bit weird, but I got javascript errors for setTimeout without that.

The timeout was added because it seemed that maybe the DIV I was trying to add content to might not exist yet due to the way Blazor formats pages, so this was a suggestion to overcome that.

When this runs, I just see nothing where I would hope the product title, description and price should appear.

In Google Play, I have a subscription set up with product ID "goldmonthly1" and within this a plan with id "goldplan1". I have tried both IDs, neither pulls anything out (Google doesn't really make it clear which of these IDs I should use, but neither works). I have triple checked the case and spellings are correct.

This is the .razor page section with the DIVs

```
        <div id="divGoogleDigitalGoodsAndBilling">
            <div id="divProductDetails"></div>
        </div>

        <div id="divGoogleDigitalGoodsOnly">
            <h2>Subscriptions</h2>
            <p>Digital Goods API is available but Google Play Billing is not supported!</p>
        </div>

        <div id="divNeither">
            <h2>Subscriptions</h2>
            <p>For the fully-featured app with paid subscriptions, 
                you will need the Google Play store version for Android.
            </p>
            <a href=""><img src="/images/google-play-badge.png" alt="Google Play" /></a>
        </div>
```

To be clear, I cannot debug javascript and step through as I would normally, because the Google Billing API simply does not work unless running in an app deployed via the Google Play store. So I am out of ideas where to go next with this if I can't even pull a simple subscription out. There is no indication in the app (e.g. Blazor error) what if anything is going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I found that when I checked the app the following day, I saw the title, though the other parts failed. I had been quite careful to clear all caches with each version I deployed, but it seems overnight something moved and by morning, I had some indication the API was retrieving data. I found from that that I needed to change a couple of things.

The description was coming un undefined. Originally, I had not set any description in Google Play for the item as they said it was optional and would not display on Google Play, but it seems it can be pulled out and displayed through the API, so I added something.

Also, price showed as [object Object]. I improved the price code, it seems the price itself is an object with value, currency and so on. The code section I have below works and displays what I would expect, title, description and a price in my local currency:

```
                // -- GOOGLE PLAY BILLING ----------------------------

                // Get a reference to the div element
                const divProductDetails = document.getElementById('divProductDetails');

                // Get SKU product details
                const skuList = ['goldmonthly1'];
                const svcProductDetails = await service.getDetails(skuList);

                // Check if any product details were retrieved
                if (svcProductDetails.length > 0) {
                    // Display debug information
                    console.log('Product Details:', svcProductDetails);

                    // Loop through (only will have one) and create text for item
                    for (const itmProduct of svcProductDetails) {

                        const localizedPrice = new Intl.NumberFormat(
                            navigator.language,
                            { style: 'currency', currency: itmProduct.price.currency }
                        ).format(itmProduct.price.value);

                        divProductDetails.innerHTML = `<h3>${itmProduct.title}</h3>
                            <p>${itmProduct.description}</p>
                            <p>Price: ${localizedPrice}</p>`;
                    }
                } else {
                    // No product details retrieved
                    console.error('No product details retrieved.');
                }

                // -- END --------------------------------------------
```

It would still really help if there was some kind of sandbox for the API, or a dummy version that could be used outside of a TWA. I am pondering whether something that would let me write javascript within my TWA would be worth adding, so I can deploy that and then work on the javascript with the Billing API without having to keep uploading new files, then just copy the code into my app once it is finished and working.